# Can't push image - fails with "no basic auth credentials"

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab, cicd

GitLab CICD Pipeline failed in the development stage, Successfully built and tagged but Failed while push refers to Amazon repository(ECR).

```
*6be90f1a2d3f: Preparing
no basic auth credentials
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables 
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the value of your GitLab job secrets regarding:

- `AWS_REGISTRY_URL`
- `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION`
- `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`
- `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`

As in [this thread](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/no-basic-auth-for-ECR-push-causing-failure/qaq-p/1110504) (for a bitBucket pipeline, but can be applied to a GitLab one), your pipeline should include a login step

`eval $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region YOUR-REGION-HERE | sed 's|https://||')`

> make sure to change the region from `YOUR-REGION-HERE` to the one you are trying to deploy to. For me this is `--region ap-southeast-2`.